# Cannot get desired results for sum of cubes of the digits of a number equal to the number

Tags: python

My goal for this program is to find the sum of cubes of the digits of a number equal to the number. They are 153, 370, 371, and 407. The following python 3.9 code is my attempt.

```
num = 1000
for a in range(1,num):
    sum = 0
    test = a
    while test>0:
        digit = test %10
        test //= 10
        cube = digit ** 3
        sum += cube
        if test == sum:
            print(test)
```

I instead get

```
1
The thread 'MainThread' (0x1) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
8
1
1
2
27
64
8
8
9
9
The program 'python.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

What can I do to get my desired results? Thank you all who helped in advance, I appreciate it.

Comment: Should you be comparing `test == sum`? Does that align with your stated goal?

Comment: Since a cannot change, I plug it in test. Then if test is equal to the sum of the cubes of the digits, yes it aligns with my goal. One example, 153: 1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3 = 153

Comment: Are you seeking the number which is the sum is equal to every digit cube?

Comment: Yes, and the correct answers are in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

```
Your code should be as below

num = 1000

for a in range(1,num):
    sum = 0
    test = a
    while test>0:
        digit = test %10
        test //= 10
        cube = digit ** 3
        sum += cube
        

    if a == sum:
        print(a)
```

Comment: So the if statement is outside of the while loop. I'll try it.

Comment: This is the result:
0
0
0
0
0
The thread 'MainThread' (0x1) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program 'python.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

Comment: based on the result that you are showing seems that the if statement is outside of for loop.  It should be inside for loop and outside of while look.   I have executed the above code on 3.8 and 3.9 and it works good

Comment: I moved the if statement so that it's in the for loop but outside the while loop and I got zeros

Comment: I tried your code on Repl.it and it worked. My current IDE is Visual Studios. Not sure how that could happen

Comment: It seems like the difference is the blank line between num and the for loop. That solved the problem. Weird though...

Comment: My bad. In your code you printed a instead of mine which is test. The code now works. Thank you so much!

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_

Answer (score 0):

```
num = 1000
for a in range(1,num):
    sum = 0
    test = a
    while test>0:
        digit = test %10
        test //= 10
        cube = digit ** 3
        sum += cube
    
    if a == sum:
        print(test)
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_